# I can't get a javascript promise to wait for adding or removing element? (Only seems to wait for setTimeout())

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have the following, very simple javascript code:

```
function addPicture(name){
    var src = document.getElementById("mainConsole");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload=function() {
        img.id=name;
        src.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.src = name;
}

function clearpicture(name){
  var elem = document.getElementById(name);
  elem.remove();
}
```

This seems to work fine as long as these functions aren't isolated in rapid succession.  Making the user click on a link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clearpicture('1.jpg');">test1</a>
```

removes the picture as one would expect.  However, if I just use this code:

```
addPicture("1.jpg");
clearpicture(1.jpg");
```

I get: `TypeError: elem is null`.  I can solve this problem with a promise!

```
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)
    console.log("now");
}).then(function(result) {
    clearpicture("1.jpg");
});
```

Everything works normally (after the delay specified of course.) Then, I tried to make the promise wait on the addpicture subroutine instead of setTimeout:

```
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    addPicture("1.jpg","1",100,0,0);
resolve(1);
    
}).then(function(result) {
    clearpicture("1.jpg");
    console.log("picture removed");
});
```

I get the same `null` error.  In my actual application, I have time for the image to load but if I try to remove a series of pictures at once:

```
clearpicture("1.jpg");
clearpicture("2.jpg");
clearpicture("3.jpg");
```

Nothing gets removed - although note there would be some delay since both of my subroutines do some processing before actually adding or removing anything.

How can I make javscript code wait on an image to be fully loaded **or** actually removed before it does anything else?

Comment: Make your addpicture function return a Promise that is resolved by the img tag's onload event.

Comment: You have to run `resolve()` inside `img.onload()` function.

Comment: Would there ever be something like an img.onunload?  I think I need to to the same thing for removing an image as well.  By the way, by passing `resolve` to the addpicture function, I managed to make it work for the loading case.

Answer (score 2):

```
function addPicture(name){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    var src = document.getElementById("mainConsole");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload=function() {
        img.id=name;
        src.appendChild(img);
        img.src = name;
        return resolve(1)
    }
    
   img.onerror = function(){return reject()}
 }
}

addPicture.then(()=>clearPicture(name))

function clearpicture(name){
  var elem = document.getElementById(name);
  elem.remove();
}
```

Comment: Is there an "unload" function as well?

Comment: There is an `onemptied` event listener for media tags. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/emptied_event

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addPicture(name){
    var src = document.getElementById("mainConsole");
    var img = new Image();
    return new Promise(v => ( img.onload = _ => ( img.id = name
                                                , src.appendChild(img)
                                                , v(name)
                                                )
                            , img.src = name
                            ));
}

function clearPicture(name){
  var elem = document.getElementById(name);
  elem.remove();
}

function delay(value,ms){
  return new Promise(v => setTimeout(v,ms,value));
}

addPicture("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1Ne1hqOXKKI/maxresdefault.jpg").then(name => delay(name,1000))
                                                                  .then(clearPicture);
```

```css
img {
  height : 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainConsole"></div>
```

Display for 1 sec and then remove.